# Is id of an UIElement created programmatically generated automatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

If I create any element from storyboard then I can see its id in the source code of Storyboard.

For Example :-  button opaque="NO" id="DDH-zU-J2t"

So if I create any element programatically then its id is created automatically or not? And if it is created, then how can I access that?

Comment: what the purpose u want to do this task

Comment: I want to identify the elements for testing.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Pretty sure that `id` in the Storyboard source is ***NOT*** available at run-time. It's part of Xcode's Interface Builder functionality.

Answer (score 0):

For automation testing purpose u can use accessibilityIdentifer.

> self.yourObject.accessibilityIdentifier = "anyName"

Comment: But my question is from where can I get the object id of an element created programmatically or there is no any id created for the elements created programatically?

Comment: AFAIK there is no such id created programmatically. If your task is to identify elements in testing, you can use the above method to set id for an element.